# Removing widget using delete button, but not reflecting on screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of widget, there is a delete button but when I press the button it should remove the widget from the listview but it is not working.

```
List<Widget> items = []; //list of widget
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
         onPressed: () {
        }),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: allRowsLength == null ? 0 : allRowsLength,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            return NoteC(

              ontap: () async {
                //save button
              },
              onPress: () async {
                //delete button
                setState(() {
                  _delete(
                      index); // deleting data from database (which works) and widget(which is not working)
                });
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void _delete(index) {
    //delete function
    setState(() {
      getID = allRows[index]['_id'];
      print('delete $getID');
      dbHelper.delete(getID);

      items.removeAt(index); 
    });
  }
```

widget is removed from the list of widgets but it is not reflecting in the listview builder

Comment: can add more code for the `ListView.builder`

Comment: You miss a lot of code, so I just guess that `dbHelper.delete` is `async`, and you called It without `await`, and then you refresh but data is same because of `delete` is not completed.